# MySQL finding the most similar user

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table that looks like this:

```
Mark - Green
Mark - Blue
Mark - Red
Adam - Yellow
Andrew - Red
Andrew - Green
```

And my objective is to compare the user "Mark" with all the other users in the database, to find out which other user he is most similar to. In this case, he would be most similar to Andrew (2/3 matches), and least similar to Adam (0/3) matches. After I've found out which user is most similar to Mark I would like to extract the entires that Andrew got but Mark doesn't.

Would this be possible in MySQL? I appreciate all help, thank you guys!

Edit: OVERWHELMED by all the good help! THANK you SO MUCH guys! I will be sure to check out all of your contributions!

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Are name and color stored in different columns?

Comment: Yep. Two different columns!

Comment: So, how do you consider "matches" on duplicates?  If the data were (Mark, Red), (Mark, Red), (Andrew, Red) how does Mark score against Andrew?  Two matches, or one match?

Comment: That's a really good question. That would be ONE match.

Comment: @binnathon Your example shows both Mark & Andrew having Red twice however.

Comment: Ya, I simplified it to make it clear, didn't think of the good question Lustig had :P

Comment: You might want to update your question then using the edit link.  Also giving expected output helps to make a question clearer.

Comment: @binnathon I've attached my answer. It filters out duplicate values in `name, color` pairs. You can try it out.

Answer (score 1):

The following query attempts to list all the users with the number of matches to `Mark`. It basically joins the table with `Mark`'s entries and counts the common entries for all users.

```
SELECT ours.user, theirs.user, count(*) as `score`
FROM tableName as `theirs`, (SELECT *
                              FROM tableName
                              WHERE user = 'Mark') as `ours`
WHERE theirs.user != 'Mark' AND
      theirs.color = ours.color
GROUP BY theirs.user
ORDER BY score DESC
```

The query, however, wouldn't work if there's duplicate data (i.e. one person picks the same color twice). But that shouldn't be a problem as you mention in the comments that it wouldn't occur.

The query can be modified to show the score for all users:

```
SELECT ours.user as `myUser`, theirs.user as `theirUser`, count(*) as `score`
FROM tableName as `ours`, tableName as `theirs`
WHERE theirs.user != ours.user AND
      theirs.color = ours.color
GROUP BY ours.user, theirs.user
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Let `Q` be the above query that gives you the most similar user. Once you have that user, you can use it to show the distinct entries between them. Here's what we're trying to do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName as theirs
WHERE user = 'Andrew'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM tableName as ours
                WHERE ours.user = 'Mark'
                      AND ours.color = theirs.color)
```

Replacing the inputs `Andrew` and `Mark` from `Q`:

```
SELECT similar.myUser, theirs.user, theirs.color  
FROM tableName as theirs JOIN (Q) as similar
ON theirs.user = similar.theirUser
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tableName as ours
                  WHERE ours.user = similar.myUser
                        AND ours.color = theirs.color)
```

[Here's the final query up and running](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9268f/1). Hope this makes sense.

Comment: No, the OP suggests that one user *can* pick the same color more than once, and that you need to actually count the matches per color.

Comment: This is input specific solution :(

Comment: @LarryLustig They edited the comment which mentioned that. However, handling duplicates the way they want (considering only 1 match) shouldn't be tough though, only a matter of selecting distinct elements.

Comment: @ConsiderMe The query can be extended to show a list for all users if that's what you want.

Comment: This does indeed work. Thank you! However, how would I extend it to find all the entires that the most similar user has but Mark doesn't have? E.G output "blue" in my example

Answer (score 0):

Use [FULLTEXT INDEXES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html). And your query will be like:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE MATCH (name,color) AGAINST ('Mark blue');
```

Or simplest way, is using LIKE search

```
 SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE '%Mike%' OR color = 'blue'
```

You can choose which way more suitable for you

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with the question.  The user is looking to count exact matches and not trying to match names.

Comment: Yea. I want to compare user X with all other users in the database, and find out which one he has most in common with, in terms of colorpicks.

Comment: Second version is no better.  You offer two options; the second does not attempt to answer the question (the user doesn't care how similar names are to each other, for instance).  The first also doesn't make a great deal of sense -- the user isn't looking for the word "Mark" in the color column not the word "blue" in the name column.

Comment: Yes, I re-read the question and I completly agreed with you. John Bupit answer more sutable

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    name,
    sum(case when t2.cnt > t1.cnt then t1.cnt else t2.cnt end) matches
from (
    select name, color, count(*) cnt
    from table
    where name <> 'Mark'
    group by name, color
) t1 left join (
    select color, count(*) cnt
    from table
    where name = 'Mark'
    group by color
) t2 on t2.color = t1.color
group by name
order by matches desc
```

The derived table `t1` contains the # of colors each user (except Mark) has, `t2` contains the same for Mark. The tables are then left joined on the color and the smaller of the 2 counts is taken i.e. if Amy has 2 reds and Mark has 1 red, then 1 is taken as the number of matches. Finally group by name and return the largest sum of matches.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you close.  The complexity comes from the fact that you allow each user to pick each color multiple times and require that each otherwise-identical pair be matched in the other user you're comparing to.  Therefore, we're really interested in knowing how many total color picks a user *per color* and how that number compares to the compared-to users' count for that same color.

First, we create a derived relation that does the simple math for us (counting up each users' number of picks by color):

```
 CREATE VIEW UserColorCounts (User, Color, TimesSeen) 
   AS SELECT User, Color, COUNT(*) FROM YourTable GROUP BY User, Color
```

Second, we need some kind of relation that compares each color-count for the primary user to the color-counts of each secondary user:

```
 CREATE VIEW UserColorMatches (User, OtherUser, Color, TimesSeen, TimesMatched)
  AS SELECT P.User, S.User, P.Color, P.TimesSeen, LEAST(P.TimesSeen, S.TimesSeen)
  FROM UserColorCounts P LEFT OUTER JOIN UserColorCounts S
  ON P.Color = S.Color AND P.User <> S.User
```

Finally, we total up the color-counts for each primary user and compare against the matching color counts for each secondary user:

```
 SELECT User, OtherUser, SUM(TimesMatched) AS Matched, SUM(TimesSeen) AS OutOf
    FROM UserColorMatches WHERE OtherUser IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY User, OtherUser
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   select match.name, count(*) as count 
     from table 
     join table as match 
           on match.name <> table.name 
          and table.name = 'mark' 
          and match.color = table.color 
    group by match.name 
    order by count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query returns matching score between `name` and `matching_name` and the maximum score it could get, so that you know what % value your matching has.

This code counts duplicate values in `color` column as only one, so that if you have record `Mark - Red` twice, it will only count as 1.

```
select
  foo.name, foo.matching_name, count(*) AS matching_score, goo.color_no AS max_score 
from 
(
  select 
    distinct a.name, a.color, b.name AS matching_name
  from 
    (
      select name, color from yourtable
    ) a
    left join yourtable b on a.color = b.color and a.name <> b.name
  where b.name is not null
) foo
left join ( select name, count(distinct color) AS color_no from yourtable group by name ) goo
  on foo.name = goo.name
group by foo.name, foo.matching_name
```

Attaching [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2dfc7/38) to preview the output.